# Not able to run kubectl cp command in Argo workflow

Tags: kubernetes, redis, kubectl, argo-workflows, argo

I am trying to run this command in my Argo workflow

`kubectl cp /tmp/appendonly.aof redis-node-0:/data/appendonly.aof -c redis -n redis`

but I get this error

```
Error from server (InternalError): an error on the server ("invalid upgrade response: status code 200") has prevented the request from succeeding (get pods redis-node-0)
```

surprisingly when I am copying the file from a pod to local system then it is working, like this command `kubectl cp redis-node-0:/data/appendonly.aof tmp/appendonly.aof  -c redis -n redis`

Any idea what might be causing it?

Answer (score 1):

Solution -
Not sure what was causing this issue but found this command in the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#copy-files-and-directories-to-and-from-containers) that worked fine

`tar cf - appendonly.aof | kubectl exec -i -n redis redis-node-0 -- tar xf - -C /data`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).